# On which interval is $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{x^{2n}}{1+x^{2n}}$ continuous?

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, solution-verification, uniform-convergence

$g(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{x^{2n}}{1+x^{2n}}$ (Abbott Exercise 6.4.4)

Question is to find the subset of $\mathbb{R}$ where g(x) is continuous.

I wanted to know if you can verify my proof:
$x=0$ is trivial so let $x\ne0$.
$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{x^{2n}}{1+x^{2n}}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{1/x^{2n}+1}$. For $|x|\ge1$ the partial sums are increasing therefore the series diverges. Let's restrict the domain of $g$ to $|x|< 1$. Then $\left|\frac{1}{1/x^{2n}+1}\right|< \frac{1}{1/x^{2n}}=x^{2n}<c^{2n}$ where $c$ being real with $1>c>x$. But $c^{2n}$ is a geometric series with $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}c^{2n}=1/(1-c^2)$ so it is a convergent majorant for $g(x)$. Uniform convergence follows from the Weierstrass M-Test. Therefore, and because all $g_n(x)$ are continuous it follows that $g(x)$ is continuous on $[0,1)$.

Comment: Wouldn't your answer then be: continuous on $(-1,1)$?

Comment: $g(x)=g(-x)$ and $g(0)=0$. so I would think the interval could be extended to $(-1, 1)$

Comment: See for example https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1741714/42969, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2364551/42969, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3970148/42969, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3783422/42969

Comment: Yes of course :)

Comment: Thank you Martin R, thats exactly the same question - i could not find it!

Comment: Can someone tell me if the extra step with the varaible $c$ is necessary for the uniform convergence?

Comment: All found [with Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24%5Csum_%7Bn%3D0%7D%5E%7B%5Cinfty%7D%5Cfrac%7Bx%5E%7B2n%7D%7D%7B1%2Bx%5E%7B2n%7D%7D%24)

Comment: Thank you again, that is helpful!